# ASCII art - Fixed Borders in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ascii-art

I'm trying to create a program that will generate a character sheet that I will be able to change easily. However, I want it to look good so I'm going to be using some ASCII art to create borders within the sheet. I was wondering how I could create borders that utilized `|` and `-` but these are going to move when the numbers change.

I imagine there is some function I can use that might be able to place the ending `|` in the exact spot it should be and not move when the number goes from  6 to 16 or 16 to 116, or words and letters.

If anyone knows how to do this I would appreciate it highly.

Comment: Not really enough information for an answer, but you might want to meditate on why printf returns what it returns.

Comment: For C++, if you prepare the lines of output in `std::string` or `std::stringstream` objects, you can inspect the current length and add appropriate padding before adding your "drawing" characters.

Comment: First step: Decide for a language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use field-width specifiers in `printf`.  For left-justification, you add the `-` prefix.  *e.g.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf( "| Greed    : %-10d |\n", 6 );
    printf( "| Gluttony : %-10d |\n", 16 );
    printf( "| Lust     : %-10d |\n", 116 );
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
| Greed    : 6          |
| Gluttony : 16         |
| Lust     : 116        |
```

Alternatively, you could adopt a more programmatic strategy, as suggested by *rici* in the comments.  That would utilize the return value (if non-negative), which tells you how many characters were written.

Read up more on `printf` and its format specifiers here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf